# Why I can't add this remote GitHub repository to my local GIT repository as remote?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I am absolutly new in GIT and GitHub and I have the following problem trying to link my local repository to a GitHub account

I do:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/recipes (master)
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
```

where **https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git** is the https link provided by GitHub for this repository.

Why I obtain this error message? What means **No such remote 'origin'**? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command you are using is not **adding** a remote but **setting the URL of an existing remote**. The command you are looking for is

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
```

`set-url` can be used if you want to change an URL or fix a typo:

```
# Note the typo in the URL:
git remote add origin https://gmail.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
# This command fixes the typo:
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extention to this, you could use

```
git remote add --track master origin github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
git remote add --master origin github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
```

This tracks the master branch only

```
git remote add --track different-oil origin github.com/AndreaNobili/recipes.git
```

This tracks the different-oil branch